# Posicionar font-awesome ao lado do texto

Tags: css, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tenho algumas flechas que precisam ser posicionadas ao lado do texto, mas não junto com ele. Ao lado assim.

[image: Flechas corretas]

Porém não sei como posicionar elas ali, no momento estou colocando elas dentro do `p` e esta ficando no inicio do texto com um paragrafo. Precisa deixar elas fora e somente posicionadas ao lado, eu tentei com uma div fora, porém dai ela quebra pra baixo e a flecha fica em cima e o texto em baixo.

[image: Como esta]

**Como ela está atualmente.**

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-fluid mr-5" src="img/img-servico-1.jpg" alt="Estádio de futebol">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4 class="text-left">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
        <h6 class="text-left mb-5">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores libero aliquid odio. Magnam, accusamus atque. Fugit culpa rem assumenda, eaque beatae, illo consequuntur odio ullam debitis praesentium eos! Laboriosam, dolores!</h6>
        <p class="text-left"><i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aperiam eius doloremque odio aspernatur itaque ratione fugit quasi? Consequuntur tempora eos id porro aliquam ratione deserunt odit, quibusdam optio reprehenderit.</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text-left">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, eius. Minus, non nam! Placeat eveniet architecto distinctio laboriosam animi facilis magnam, sunt corporis dicta nisi non inventore, minima repudiandae? Expedita!</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text-left">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem odit fugit quibusdam ipsum. Sapiente facere ut rerum quibusdam ipsa quos voluptatibus. At quas nesciunt dolore repudiandae. Laudantium harum saepe deleniti!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Outro problema que preciso deixar a imagem maior se encontrando com a outra que vem em baixo porem do outro lado, só que a classe `img-fluid` deixa ela muito pequena.

Comment: Cara sobre a lista de ícones deixei a resposta ai de uma forma melhor e mais semântica de fazer, Já sobre a imagem não entendi direito o que vc quer... Evite entrar em dois assuntos totalmente diferentes em uma pergunta só, isso deixa as coisas meio confusas e não é bom para o sistema tipo Q&A, o ideal é que separe suas perguntas por Assunto entende... Mas de mais detalhes ai que eu tento te ajudar com isso tb

Comment: @hugocsl Sim, erro meu, vou fazer outra pergunta com o assunto da imagem.

Comment: Isso ai, assim fica melhor pra te responder e mantem cada pergunta dentro de um escopo definido, isso é melhor até para o SEO do site. Qq coisa me da um toque que te dou uma força, é só vc colocar o código do seu problema direitinho

Comment: @hugocsl fiz a pergunta lá sobre a imagem. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/352565/91948

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara sobre os ícones do Fontawesome a forma mais fácil pra vc ajustar ao meu ver é criar um `UL/LI` com o ícone dentro, ai vc pode usar as classes de `Margin` do Bootstrap tipo `mr-x` e `mt-x` etc para ajustar tudo, vc tb precisa colocar cada `LI` com `d-flex` (`display:flex`) classe original do Bootstrap.

Veja o exemplo como fica. Não precisa de CSS extra, é tudo com as classes *default* do BS4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-fluid mr-5" src="img/img-servico-1.jpg" alt="Estádio de futebol">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4 class="text-left">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
      <h6 class="text-left mb-5">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores libero aliquid odio. Magnam, accusamus atque. Fugit culpa rem assumenda, eaque beatae, illo consequuntur odio ullam debitis praesentium eos! Laboriosam, dolores!</h6>
      <ul class="lista p-0 m-0">
        <li class="d-flex mb-2"><i class="fa fa-rocket mt-1 mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, maiores. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, perspiciatis.</li>
        <li class="d-flex mb-2"><i class="fa fa-rocket mt-1 mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, maiores. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, perspiciatis.</li>
        <li class="d-flex mb-2"><i class="fa fa-rocket mt-1 mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, maiores. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, perspiciatis.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: E também pode adicionar a classe `align-items-center` no  `<li class="d-flex mb-2">` para o `FontAwesome` ficar centralizado verticalmente

Comment: @IcaroMartins isso mesmo! Já que o display já é flex fica fácil esse ajusta :D, é uma boa dica!