# Deixar imagens juntas e responsivas

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Preciso deixar as imagens se encontrarem uma embaixo da outra, ocupando metade do container e ao seu lado a descrição dessa imagem.

Ela precisa ficar desse formato.

[image: Como é para ficar]

**No momento ela esta assim**
[image: Como esta]

Porém ai ela ta ocupando somente o tamanho definido `col-md-6`, e ela deveria ocupar uns 60% do container inteiro, de lado a lado da tela, e o conteúdo sim ser centralizado, porém o conteúdo quando diminui a tela está ficando por cima da imagem.

Minha duvida é como deixar as imagens juntas ali, uma encostando na outra no canto inferior direito **da primeira** e superior esquerdo **da segunda**

```
      <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class='img-container'>
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/img-servico-1.jpg" alt="Estádio de futebol">
            <div class='triangle'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-5">
          <h4 class="text-left">Lorem..</h4>
          <h6 class="text-left mb-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consectetur, veniam!
          </h6>
          <ul class="lista p-0 m-0">
            <li class="d-flex mb-2 align-items-center"><i class="fas fa-angle-right mt-1 mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis velit repellat repudiandae?
            </li>
            <li class="d-flex mb-2 align-items-center"><i class="fas fa-angle-right mt-1 mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto dolorem temporibus veritatis itaque. </li>
            <li class="d-flex mb-2 align-items-center"><i class="fas fa-angle-right mt-1 mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, esse animi deserunt ullam distinctio alias.
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p class="pt-5"><a class="button button-rouded btn-big js-scroll" href="#sobre" role="button">Saiba Mais</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 mt-5">
          <h4 class="text-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</h4>
          <h6 class="text-right mb-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis?
          </h6>
          <ul class="lista p-0 m-0">
            <li class="d-flex text-right mb-2 align-items-center"></i>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla voluptatem voluptatum ratione ut! Perspiciatis, eos aperiam atque neque at esse praesentium sit, doloribus dolor blanditiis a excepturi incidunt? Quis, quibusdam? <i class="fas fa-angle-left mt-1 ml-3"
                aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="d-flex text-right mb-2 align-items-center"></i>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis ab quis neque inventore quisquam placeat, suscipit error officia eveniet! Iste nam minus perferendis nihil ullam facere accusamus obcaecati porro delectus?
              <i class="fas fa-angle-left mt-1 ml-3" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>

          </ul>
          <p class="pt-4"><a class="button button-rouded btn-big js-scroll" href="#sobre" role="button">Saiba Mais</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class='img-container'>
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/img-servico-2.jpg" alt="Estádio de futebol">
            <div class='triangle-left'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS DA IMAGEM**

```
.img-container {
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   position: relative;
}

.img-container > img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Vc está usando algum CSS além do do original do BS4? Se estiver inclua tb na pergunta

Comment: Editado com o css que to usando no container da imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara segue uma opção, ela usa a imagem como background-image da `div` e não com a tag `<img>`, mas caso seja imprescindível usar a tag `<img>` me fala, pois tb é possível adaptar com ela, o problema é que fica meno *crossbrowser*, pois usa propriedades que não são aceitas em browsers mais antigos...

Esse CSS que vc está usando não fica legal, ele fica pouco responsivo pois tem valores fixos. Também precisei fazer alguns ajuste no seu HTML, pois a forma como vc montou o Grid não estava legal. Veja como eu fiz e tome como base...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja esse modelo que fiz. No CSS criei duas classes, uma com cada imagem, e coloquei direto na `div col-` Exiba em "Página toda" para ver a responsividade.

**OBS**: precisei fazer um `@media screen and (max-width: 767px)` para dizer que em tela abaixo disso a div da imagem vai ter uma altura de 300px. Deixei comentado no código

```css
.bg1,
.bg2 {
  background-image: url(https://placecage.com/200/200);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bg2 {
  background-image: url(https://fillmurray.com/200/200);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px)  {
  .bg1,
  .bg2 {
    height: 300px !important; /* altura mínama pra imagem quando a tela for menor que 575px*/
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- imagem -->
    <div class="col-md-6 bg1"></div>

    <div class="col-md-6 mt-5">
      <h4 class="text-left">Lorem..</h4>
      <h6 class="text-left mb-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consectetur, veniam!
      </h6>
      <ul class="lista p-0 m-0">
        <li class="d-flex mb-2 align-items-center"><i class="fas fa-angle-right mt-1 mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis velit repellat repudiandae?
        </li>
        <li class="d-flex mb-2 align-items-center"><i class="fas fa-angle-right mt-1 mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto dolorem temporibus veritatis itaque.
        </li>
        <li class="d-flex mb-2 align-items-center"><i class="fas fa-angle-right mt-1 mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, esse animi deserunt ullam distinctio
          alias.
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="pt-5"><a class="button button-rouded btn-big js-scroll" href="#sobre" role="button">Saiba Mais</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4 class="text-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</h4>
      <h6 class="text-right mb-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis?
      </h6>
      <ul class="lista p-0 m-0">
        <li class="d-flex text-right mb-2 align-items-center">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla voluptatem voluptatum ratione ut!
          Perspiciatis, eos aperiam atque neque at esse praesentium sit, doloribus dolor blanditiis a excepturi
          incidunt? Quis, quibusdam? <i class="fas fa-angle-left mt-1 ml-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="d-flex text-right mb-2 align-items-center">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis ab quis neque inventore quisquam
          placeat, suscipit error officia eveniet! Iste nam minus perferendis nihil ullam facere accusamus
          obcaecati porro delectus?
          <i class="fas fa-angle-left mt-1 ml-3" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      </ul>
      <p class="pt-4"><a class="button button-rouded btn-big js-scroll" href="#sobre" role="button">Saiba Mais</a></p>
    </div>

    <!-- imagem -->
    <div class="col-md-6 bg2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não precisa ser com o atributo img não, muito obrigado cara, você ta me salvando horrores haha

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti depois vc me manda um engradado de brahma xD

Comment: Manda o endereço ai xD.